# Popover API: How to stop the popover from closing

Tags: javascript, html, popover

When using the popover API, I would like to, when light dismiss occurs, stop the popover from closing, and run custom js to remove the popover from the screen.

Is there a way to do this?

I tried to do this but this didn't work.

```html
<style>
  div {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: hotpink;
  }
</style>
<div popover></div>
<script>
  document.querySelector("div").showPopover();
  document
    .querySelector("div")
    .addEventListener("beforetoggle", (event) => {
      if (event.newState === "closed") {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();

        // Run custom JS to remove popover from dom 
      }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: coming in hot with the links. Thanks, this does solve my issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the popover as a backdrop for an internal DIV acting as an actual popover.
Then you can catch clicks and do anything you want, replace `popover.hidePopover()` to anything you want.
If you want the backdrop transparent for mouse event you should some direct them manually, an example for `click` is provided:

```js
const popover = document.querySelector("[popover]");


popover.showPopover(); popover.classList.toggle('opened');
popover.addEventListener('beforetoggle', e => popover.classList.toggle('opened', e.newState !== 'closed'));
popover.addEventListener("click", e => e.target.closest('.popover') || popover.hidePopover() || document.elementFromPoint(e.pageX, e.pageY)?.click());
```

```css
.popover{
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
    background-color: hotpink;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
    border: 1px solid gray;
    border-radius: 5px;
  }
  .backdrop{
  border:none;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background: transparent;
    }
    
    .opened{
      display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
  
  }
```

```html
<button onclick="console.log('button clicked')">Click me</button>
<button onclick="$popover.showPopover()">Show popover</button>
<div id="$popover" popover class="backdrop"><div class="popover"></div></div>
```